# How to group similar records in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a problem with grouping records based on their name of the color. Here I would like to explain with an example. I have "BLUE JEAN(3)" with the quantity 3 & "BLUE JEANS MET(7)" with the quantity 7, can we group together ? I want the output BLUE JEAN(10).

Note: These are already distributed in database with different ID. I have lots of colors so I need to group only those similar colors and need to populate for searching.

Here is my structure of coding:

Model:

```php
class MyVehicle extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'color_id',
        'stock_number'
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```php
public function searchVehicleColor()
{
    $vehicles_colors = DB::table('vehicles')
        ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(vehicles.color_id) as color_count'), 'colors.color')
        ->leftjoin('colors', 'colors.id', '=', 'vehicles.color_id')->get();

    return view('public/search_result', compact('vehicles_colors'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($vehicles_colors as $vehicles_color)
    <li>
        {{ Form::checkbox('color[]', $vehicles_color->color, null, ['class' => 'color field','id'=>$vehicles_series_color->color,'onClick'=>'reply_click(this.id)']) }}
        <label for="{{$vehicles_color->color}}">{{$vehicles_color->color}}({{$vehicles_color->color_count}})</label>
        <div class="check"></div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Here is the output , I just want to merge highlighted data.
[image]

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more precise please? What kind of object are "BLUE JEAN(3)" and "BLUE JEANS MET(7)"?

Comment: It would be better if you add Models and DB structure in your question.

Comment: Hello @louisfischer thanks for your quick response, 
These are the record I have added in database table and  have to display all of them in the front-end but similar data are repeating because of its different naming.
Here I have some kind of  "BLUE JEAN" ,"BLUE JEANS MET" and "BLUE JEANS". These are the similar data so I want to put them together to display and also want to count total number of items.

Comment: As @Laerte told you. Post your models and database structure. Without knowing what you have in your database we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function searchVehicleColor(){
$vehicles_colors = DB::table('vehicles')
->select(DB::raw('COUNT(vehicles.color_id) as color_count'),'colors.color')
->leftjoin('colors', 'colors.id', '=','vehicles.color_id')->groupBy('name')->get();
```

return view('public/search_result', compact('vehicles_colors'));
    }

Comment: Hello @Kuldeep ,it will not work for me  I don't have exactly the same name of the color. But I have the similar name like "Blue Jean" and "Blue Jeans Met"

Comment: Then you have to use same name if you want other solution  use like in you query